# WebScraping Amazons Books Names

Tags: r, web-scraping

I am trying to webscrape Amazon's books names:

```
rm(list = ls())

library(rvest)
library(XML)
library(xml2)
url_amazon <- 'https://www.amazon.com/s/browse?_encoding=UTF8&node=283155&ref_=nav_shopall-export_nav_mw_sbd_intl_books'

web_page<-read_html(url_amazon)
```

By CSS SELECTOR:

```
rank_titles<-html_text(html_nodes(web_page,".a-link-normal .a-size-base"))
```

BY XPATH SELECTOR:

```
rank_titles<-html_text(html_nodes(web_page,xpath='//span[@class="a-size-base"]'))
```

But the names of the books are not in order. Why? What am I doing wrong?

Any help?

Comment: The order seems to change everytime you run `web_page<-read_html(url_amazon)`. Why is order important ?

Comment: What is more weird is I don't see that book on my page. Are you logged in or is it based on location?

Comment: Its weird @RonakShah. Look the Book "Numerical Methods in Economics (The MIT Press)" it doesnt appear when I call "rank_titles". the question is if all the books on the page appear in "rank_titles". All the books on the page appears for you?.

Comment: No Iam not logged.

Answer (score 0):

This will grab all tables:

```
library(XML)
library(RCurl)

url <- "https://www.amazon.com/s/browse?_encoding=UTF8&node=283155&ref_=nav_shopall-export_nav_mw_sbd_intl_books"

tables <- getURL(url)
tables <- readHTMLTable(tables, stringsAsFactors = F)

#Shows you all the tables pulled
str(tables)

#To view a particular table
View(tables$results)
```